# Android Glide: wait for the future and load

Tags: android, android-glide

I've an api that returns `ListenableFuture<Uri>`.

How can I ask glide to wait for future and then load the uri?

I've looked [online](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads) for some help but couldn't find the exact case.

I don't want to add a listener myself to the future and then pass the actual uri value to `Glide.load` and want to do something like:

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .asDrawable()
                .load(uriFuture)
                .transform(Drawable.class, getBackgroundTransformation())
                .into(albumArtView);
```

Basically, glide should start loading the uri when future is completed.

Answer (score -1):

use the below code

```
@BindingAdapter({"bind:src_url", "bind:progress"})
public static void setChatSrcUrl(final ImageView view, String sourceUrl, final ProgressBar pb) {
    if (sourceUrl == null) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_wifi);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .asBitmap()
                .load(sourceUrl)
                .override(250, 400)
                .fitCenter()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .error(R.drawable.gray_wifi)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(view);
    }
}
```